Nginx connection refused error when serving from /usr/share/nginx/html
We have a kubernetes cluster with a nginx alpine pod hosting a angular frontend that has been built and placed in the /usr/share/nginx/html folder. The pod is being connected to by an ingress that is returning a 502. The frontend is working intermittently but there are very frequent 111 connection refused errors coming from the nginx pod when requests are made for js bundles. Why would there be a connection refused error if the files are being served from the local nginx folder?

These troubleshooting steps may help you:

Check if the Nginx has any errors kubectl exec -it <nginx-pod> -- cat /var/log/nginx/error.log.
Check the nginx pod if the nginx process can access the content of the built frontend code. You can use the following code for checking file/folder permissions: ls -lah /usr/share/nginx/html
typically, the nginx process user is named nginx or www-data
Check the Network Policies or Firewall of the Kubernetes cluster.
Check if Ingress or Service are misconfigured. Also check the port by default nginx uses port 80.
Pod Resource Constraints can be another reason for this issue. Please check the nginx pod logs to find any issue reguarding configuration or resource constraints. You can use kubectl logs to chekc logs. You can also use kubectl describe pod <nginx-pod> to check if the pod is restarting frequently.


the problem ended up being that the ingress controller was routing some requests to the database pod, Still no idea why it worked sometimes and not others
